# Rotate an object with RotateAround to a specific value

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm new in unity engine and try to rotate an object to specific value, but could not find any answer!

For example, I have an Euler angles (0,0,48) and my object in (0,0,340). I want give (0,0,48) values to my object with RotateAround() function to my object. Because it should rotate around of a point!

Comment: Could you please clarify your example? Is your object's current rotation of euler angles (0, 0, 340), and you wish to give it a rotation of euler angles (0, 0, 48)?

Comment: yes juliasaurus ... but I have to use "RotateAround()" function and should not set it direct

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a point in space you wish to rotate through, use `Transform.Rotate()`. that should be more than enough for you to rotate an object by (0,0,48) like you said.

Comment: my object should rotate around of a point that is a dynamic point.!
I have to set Euler angles with something like "RotateAround()" function. that should not set direct

Comment: That is not going to give you your desired effect, setting `eulerAngles` will rotate it in place. Like i said, unless you have a point in space you want to rotate **through**, don't use `RotateAround(...)`. Instead what you can do, if you have a "dynamic pivot" is to use an empty `GameObject` as the pivot point, set it where you need it, parent it to your object you wish to rotate, rotate it, then unparent it and move it again.

Comment: change it to parent and unparent is not an optimize and good way.I'm think about a way to convert 'eulerAngles' to 'RotateAround()' ... !!!

Comment: do u even realize that you can't rotate an object around a point by setting only its `eulerAngles`? you have to move it's `position` as well so good luck.

Comment: yes Mr. @Andrew ... I work it for that!! maybe I will make a formula for do it